# replace all non word characters in utf8 string

Tags: php, regex

how can i replace all non word characters (utf-8) in a string ?

for ASCII:

```
$url = preg_replace("/\W+/", " ", $url);
```

is there any equivalent for UTF-8 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the *Xwd* character class that contains letters, digits and underscore:

```
$url = preg_replace('~\P{Xwd}+~u', ' ', $url);
```

If you don't want the underscore, you can use *Xan*

`\p{Xwd}` (Perl word character) is a predefined character class and `\P{Xwd}` is the negation of this class.

The `u` modifier means that the string must be treated as an unicode string.

equivalence:

```
\p{Xan}        <=>     [\p{L}\p{N}]
\p{Xwd}        <=>     [\p{Xan}_]
```

Comment: could you please explain this regex ? it seems that this work.i am testing it.

Comment: +1, I didn't know `Xwd` property.

Comment: @M42: Thanks, all the secrets are here: http://pcre.org/pcre.txt

Answer (score 2):

Use unicode properties:

```
$url = preg_replace("/[^\p{L}\p{N}_]+/u", " ", $url);
```

`\p{L}` stands for any letter
`\p{N}` stands for any number.

Comment: its return this: �-�-�-�-�-�-�-�-�-�-�-�-�-�-�-�-�- for $url = preg_replace("/[^\p{L}\p{N}_]+/", "-", $url);

Comment: must be "/[^\p{L}\p{N}_]+/u" , but i am not sure whats difference between these two answer.

Comment: @UFO: Yes, I forgot the `/u` modifier that deals with unicode.